# checking for Null in a date Asp, VB, SQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

how do I check for Null with a date please?
Here's what I tried..

```
Dim playDate As Date = 
order.SelectPlayDate(Guid.Parse(returnedItem.orderID))

If playDate Not IsNull Then
    calendar1.SelectedDate = playDate
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

The error because the value you declare to playDate can return a null. You should check first if this "order.SelectPlayDate(Guid.Parse(returnedItem.orderID))" contains value before declaring to playDate

Maybe like this(not tested):

```
    If order.SelectPlayDate(Guid.Parse(returnedItem.orderID)) <> Nothing  Then
        calendar1.SelectedDate = order.SelectPlayDate(Guid.Parse(returnedItem.orderID))
    End If
```

Or declaring first. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and get Conversion from string to type date not valid. I seen on other posts that dates can't be null but in MySQL it says Null and no matter what solutions I've tried I can't figure it.

Comment: What will happen if MySQL returns null? It sets the calendar1 to current date?